# Adding core Javascript libraries in my_module.libraries.yml

Tags: 8, javascript

I've read [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) and I can see where you can add assets that are part of your module or from a CDN or external source. What about if that library you want to add is already a core asset?

I'm trying to add `jquery.ui.accordion` to my modules so in my `*.libraries.yml` I have:

```
my_module:
  js:
    /core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/accordion-min.js: { minified: true }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery.ui
    - core/jquery.ui.widget
```

That library is never loaded. What am I missing? Is there a better way to add core assets to my module?

**EDIT:** I've also tried different paths like:

```
core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/accordion-min.js: { minified: true }
../../../core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/accordion-min.js: { minified: true }
```

Comment: I’m not sure your approach is right here

Comment: I'd agree with that. I switched it up to my answer below and that seems to work for me for now. I've been working with Drupal 8 for less than a month and Drupal itself for less than a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just scraped the `MY_MODULE.libraries.yml` and utilized one of the other methods of adding assets, by:

```
function MY_MODULE_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = "core/jquery.ui.accordion";
  //new addition below
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = "MY_MODULE/MY_MODULE.accordion";
}
```

This works for me. Perhaps you don't need a `MY_MODULE.libraries.yml` if you are trying to add libraries that already exist in core.

Edit: So I still have a `MY_MODULE.libraries.yml` file however it now just adds my module's javascript (with a dependency to jQuery). It's just some Javascript that initializes jQuery UI accordions. I still use the code above to add jQuery
s UI accordion javascript and my own.

Comment: If the library is already defined by core, you don't redefine it in your module, you just add it to #attached as you did in the line `$attachments['#attached']['library'][] = "core/jquery.ui.accordion";`